# Salesforce flow error - This error occurred when the flow tried to look up records

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a flow which was deployed to a full sandbox from a dev sandbox. The flow was tested working in the dev sandbox as well as a partial sandbox. For some reason after deploying it to the full sandbox it shows this error at the get records node of the flow. I am pulling in just one record from the task object. The below is the error I get when I debug. What could be the reason that its not working in the full sandbox?

**`Error Occurred: This error occurred when the flow tried to look up records: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1348612264-167340 (-548403183). You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide`**

Comment: did you look at the email that is generated by the Flow runtime engine?  My suspicion would be a non-selective query

Comment: That was right cropredy. I found a fix.

Comment: So the answer was a non-selective query?

Comment: I kept the query the same, but the field the query was looking up was not indexed. Indexing fixed the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasons why something that works in a dev sandbox no longer works in a full copy sandbox

1. The configurations are different. This is indicative of a failure somewhere in your DevOps process (not pushing all changes from dev upstream; making asynchronous config changes directly into upstream sandboxes; failure to address merge conflicts)
2. You have a query that is non-selective. The dev sandboxes work fine because a table scan doesn't take too long as there aren't likely to be many records.  But the full copy sandbox, is, by definition, a full copy of PROD and could have millions of records.

I would surmise in your case that the latter reason (non-selective query) is the issue, especially as the Flow fails on a `Get Records` element.

Examine your Get Records element and ensure the [query will be selective](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000325257&type=1&mode=1). This means that indexed fields should be used to help winnow down the corpus of records into an efficient search.